# API Upload files with metadata

Tags: laravel, database-design, architecture, polymorphism, nested-resources

I'm looking for some guidance here.

**Scenario:**

I have a Post model with a polymorphic relation to a Comment model. Whenever I want to create a new comment for a given post I have the following endpoint:

```
$router->post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'PostsCommentsController@store');
```

So far so good. Now I want to add an Attachment model which will also be a polymorphic relation since I may need to add attachments to more things other than comments (ex: messages, etc).

My first idea was doing something in the lines of:

```
$router->post('/posts/{post}/comments/attachments', 'PostsCommentsAttachmentsController@store');
```

**So the comment will belong to a post and will have an attachment.**

This feels a bit "dirty" to me (especially the controller name) and the need of having 3 nested resources (maybe I'm just thinking too much).

Hope I was clear enough explaining my problem :)

---

Have anyone faced something like this before? How did you guys solve it?

Other approaches? Am I thinking completely wrong?

Open to ideas and suggestions :D

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer `Single Responsibility` for each `Controllers` or `route`. So it's pretty clear what their actually do and handle. Let me give you example:

```
- Post
/posts               -> list all post
/posts/{id}          -> get specific post
/posts/{id}/comments -> get comments of the post

- Comment
/comments/{id}            -> get specific comment
/comments/{id}/attacments -> get attacments of a comment

- Attachment
/attachment/{id} -> get specific attachment
```

For `Controller` name, just keep it simple. Just use`PostController`, `CommentController` and `AttachmentController`. It's quite clear I think.

Comment: Thanks. My `comments` table has these two fields: `commentable_id`(post_id, tasks_id, etc) and the `commentable_type`( a string that can be 'posts', 'tasks', etc) so when I create a comment I need to dynamically know its type and the same happens to the attachment (it can be in the context of a comment or a chat message). 

So should I first make a request to `/posts/{id}/comments` to create and get the comment resource in the response and then do another request to `/comments/{id}/attachments' so I can specify the attachment is in the context of a comment?

Comment: Do you mean submiting a comment of a post and the comment has an attachment with it?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that.

Comment: Actually you doesn't need put not every process in `controller`. Because when you put it in `controller`, it's mean you should call it via `http` request. I suggest, you create a `helper` class or `helper` function. So you can call it in every place you need it. Even in many `controller`. I hope you can understand. I am sorry, if my explanation is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

After more researching, I actually realized that what I wanted to do was basically a file upload with metadata.

Came across this excellent post: [HTTP/REST API File Uploads](https://philsturgeon.uk/api/2016/01/04/http-rest-api-file-uploads) that explains it

PS: Thank you Dharma for the help and time.